# Can I free memory depending on if there is something to free?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to eliminate all memory leaks from some messy code. I have a class `Employee` with the member `name_` which gets allocated on the heap with a `new *char` during runtime. Now there are some instances where `name_`gets deleted manually before `Employee`'s destructor gets called. I know this is bad practice. However, there are some cases where I still need `name_` to be deleted through the destructor. I tried things like

```
Employee::~Employee(){
  if (this->name_)
  {
    delete[] this->name_;
  }
}
```

or

```
if (this->name_ != NULL)
{
  delete[] this->name_;
}
```

or

```
if (this->name_[0] != '\0')
{
  delete[] this->name_;
}
```

But those options didn't realize `name_` has already been delted somewhere else and tried to delete something which didn't exist anymore.

So I would need something like

```
if (char* name_ not deleted yet)
{
  delte name_
}
```

Is there a way to check withing an `if` weather a member has already been deleted?

Edit: 
Thanks for the link to the question that already answered mine, indeed it does!

Comment: Use `std::string` and let the standard library implementation handle the memory management for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Unfortunately not possible since this is for an assignement and there are some things I am not allowed to change, such as the type of `name_` being `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on managing memory for `name_` manually (instead of using `std::string`), you can simply encapsulate it into your class and `delete` it manually via some `reset()` function that sets `name_` to `nullptr` after deleting it. Then in your destructor, you simply check if `name_` is not `nullptr` and `delete` it.

Comment: It is safe to call `delete` on a null pointer, so there is no need to check for null before calling `delete`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, great notice! Don't know why I decided to recheck it. Thank you for the edit!